# Import pexpect in child module - 'no module named pexpect'

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, importerror, pexpect

I'm seeing weird behavior that I don't understand, so I'm turning to the experts here on SO for help.  I have looked at similar questions, without finding anything that looked helpful.

I'm writing a program that imports two custom modules.

If I run the main program using the cli **"./ld_config_automation.py"** I get the following error:

```
laptop$ ./ld_config_automation.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ld_config_automation.py", line 34, in <module>
    from modules.networkcomponent import NetworkComponent
  File "/path/to/pprograms/ssh_telnet_automation/modules/networkcomponent.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pexpect
ImportError: No module named pexpect
```

However, if I run the main program using the cli **"python ld_config_automation.py"** everything works fine and the program runs.

My main program uses the following import statements.

```
import sys
import getopt
from modules.networkcomponent import NetworkComponent
from modules.recordclass import Record
```

The module I'm having trouble with "NetworkComponent" uses the following import statements:

```
import re
import pexpect
```

Also, if I remove import pexpect from the NetworkComponent module it works as expected without python in front (up to when it has to use pexpect. of course). So it doesn't seem to be a problem with importing modules, as re works ok, just not pexpect.

I'm developing this on mac os X but will implement on CentOS.

Comment: ld_config_automation.py may be using a different python. Check its "shebang" (the first line) to see what its pointing to.

Comment: First, thank you @tdelaney that worked.  I have both anaconda and the default python installed and changing the 'shebang' to anaconda worked.  However, it is still strange because in the interpreter for both default and anaconda 'import pexpect' works.  Still something here I'm not understanding but It is working now.  I have the python env variable set to anaconda but on the target system it will be a default installation, so in the meantime I'll change my env variable which should get me through.

Comment: Hello Future People reading this Question ::::>   To solve this issue, I ended up changing my PYTHONPATH back to /usr/bin and started running into issues again.  Even though it looked like pexpect was installed or available in the default installation, it actually wasn't.  I uninstalled anaconda (just renamed the dir) and then used pip to install pexpect.  Bingo...  everything working as expected (pun intended).